# How do I download a Google Gode Java project?

Tags: android, google-code

I see a project here at Google Open Source, but I don't see a download link. How do I download the code?

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/aecdc4a41f1f2f3e76e05d6549df75359f8397c3/uiautomator/utils/uiautomatorviewer/

I tried from their GitHub page, but I didn't find it there:

https://github.com/google?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&type=&language=

Comment: Click the `tgz` link

Comment: You can actually download sources from the standalone SDK manager. https://i.stack.imgur.com/utCMv.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tgz format can be extracted using WinZip for tgz. Thanks Adam and Veneet.